# Create jquery variable from a php/sql query / JSON query

Tags: jquery, sql, arrays, json, variables

i have been searching this wonderful site of information but havent found exactly what im looking for, only bits and pieces .

Im fairly new to the whole JavaScript language/jQuery library but im begining to love it more and more with the things you can do with it.

I have a file, array.php, that print out json formatted variable with certain dates that i want to disable in a .datepicker calendar.

I have got the whole thing working except the variable from sql part.

This works: `var $BadDates = new Array("2012-05-28","2012-05-29","2012-05-30");`

What i would like is something like this:

```
$.getJSON('array.php', function(data) {
var $BadDates = [];
}
```

My array.php:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM dates";
$query_result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$results = array();


while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_result)) {



  $n["startdate"] = $row['startdate'];


  array_push($results, $n); 
}
print json_encode($results);
```

This is what i want to accomplish (i know its all wrong, just so i can show how im thinking):

```
$BadDates = new Array("$.getJSON('array.php')");
```

Have been checking out many solutions without any luck...

I appreciate all the help i can get!

/Oskar

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use AJAX here, though I will show you both ways:

First, since your PHP file is printing a JSON encoded string, you can just include it where necessary in your PHP generated page:

```
<?php
    /* Some php */
?>

<!-- some html -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    var badDates = <?php include('array.php'); ?>;
    /* do something with badDates, which is now a JS array */
</script>

<!-- some more html -->

<?php
    /* Some more php */
?>
```

It would output something like: http://codepad.org/4xHlcwig

For an AJAX retrieved array, you would:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        url: '/array.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            /* data contains a JS array which was outputted from your file and decoded by jQuery for you */
        }
    });

    /* -OR- your shorthand method */

    $.getJSON('array.php', function(data) {
        /* data contains a JS array which was outputted from your file and decoded by jQuery for you */

    }
</script>
```